# How to check downloaded files Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I wrote an automation test in Selenium webdriver using C#, and one of steps requires to download a XLSX file from server. How to validate if file has downloaded successfully and get his name?

Regards

Comment: while starting the webdriver, give a default download path. After downloading the file, check whether some xlsx exists inside the download path...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution with following source code:

```cs
string currentPage = Browser.Current.Url;
string userPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
string downloadPath = Path.Combine(userPath, "Downloads");

DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(downloadPath);

if (!dirInfo.Exists)
{
     dirInfo.Create();
}

int directoryFiles = dirInfo.EnumerateFiles().Count();

string elementXpath = "//div[@id='myDiv']/div/div/div[@class='atalhos']/a[1]";

bool isFirefox = (Browser.Current as FirefoxDriver) != null;
bool isChrome = (Browser.Current as ChromeDriver) != null;

IWebDriver browserDriver = null;

if (isChrome)
{
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadPath);
    chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");

    browserDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
}
else if (isFirefox)
{               
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();                
    profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);                
    profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

    browserDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
}

browserDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(currentPage);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browserDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(elementXpath)));

IWebElement elemento = browserDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(elementXpath));

elemento.Click();

Thread.Sleep(7000);

dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(downloadPath);

int currentFiles = dirInfo.EnumerateFiles().Count();

Assert.Greater(currentFiles, directoryFiles);
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume that you run the browser on the same machine as your code? If you use e.g. Browserstack how would you get access to the directory on a remote machine?

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue I run the webdriver in a docker container and mount a data volume into it to host the files.  Then I can run another docker container with the same volume mounted and contents elsewhere using a traditional method.

Comment: @Wyck Great, I am not saying it's not possible. The point I am making that building non-portable solution might kick you back if you plan to use remote / 3rdparty. In your case even though Docker containers are not aware of each other, they're not remote, they share the same machine.
Ideally the Selenium API should allow fetching data from the browser.

I've given up trying to use Selenium for that, I am just using browser to get to the point when the file needs to be downloaded, then I am "scraping" all of the cookies and issuing cURL request, so I can get file reliably.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, i have taken the list of excel files in the download folder. If you have only one file then use file.name property or if you have multiple files try the below code.

```cs
 private static string GetDownloadedFileName()
    {
          var fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["excelName"].ToString();
          string pathUser=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
          string pathDownload = Path.Combine(pathUser, "Downloads");

            DirectoryInfo downloadDir = new DirectoryInfo(pathDownload);
            FileInfo[] files = downloadDir.GetFiles("*.xls");
            var file = files.Where(x => x.Name.Replace(" ", "") == fileName + ".xls").FirstOrDefault();
            fileName = file.FullName;

            return fileName;
    }
```