# Verifying downloading file address

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

Let's assume that we have button and clicking on it triggers downloading xls document:

```js
function download() {
  window.open("http://opendatakit.org/wp-content/uploads/static/sample.xls")
}
```

```html
<input value="Download" type="button" onclick="download()">
```

[See how it works here](http://jsfiddle.net/d1eht9s3/): location seems to change for a moment and document is being downloaded.

Let's assume that we want to write Selenium tests for that code.

**Question**: How can I verify (i.e. with js) if clicking on button triggers downloading file from proper address?

I tried to find some trace of change of location in `window.history` (`window.history(-1), window.history(1)`), but it seems that this change is not noticed.

**Edit:**
I don't want to verify file content. I wan't to **verify if file is downloaded from proper URL**. I don't want to test service that prepares and provides file.

Comment: See [How best to test file download links using Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15400/how-best-to-test-file-download-links-using-selenium) on 
Software Quality Assurance & Testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check downloaded files Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573483/how-to-check-downloaded-files-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: I don't want to verify file content. I wan't to verify if file is downloaded from proper URL.

Comment: if you are using the chrome web driver, you can open the downloads tab using "chrome://downloads/". You can get the download link

Comment: The duplicate doesn't check file contents. It just checks if a file with that name was downloaded. If the url is incorrect, you will likely not get that file. Maybe not 100% certain, but possibly the best you can do.

Comment: Selenium server is not running on the same machine as the test execution and I don't have possibility to check if file exist on that machine.

Comment: @AmanB "chrome://downloads" indeed solve my problem. I can get the download link there. Please consider add this as an answer.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the chrome web driver, you can open the downloads tab using "chrome://downloads/". You can get the download link